# iPhone jsonp callback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have a sample webpage I'm testing various jQuery calls with JSONP to my WCF Service.

I call the JSONP like this, cross-domain by the way:

```
$.getJSON("http://myserver:port/GetNowPlayingJson?method=?", getNowPlayingResponse);
```

And in my callback function (getNowPlayingResponse), something simple to update the page html:

```
$("#lblNowPlaying").text(data.FormattedArtistTitle + " - " + data.RemainingTime);
```

My JSONP calls work just fine on:

- Firefox 4
- IE9
- Chrome 12
- iPad2 4.3.3

But not on iPhone 3GS 4.1

I can see the data transfer status indicator in the iPhone status bar come up briefly when I try to make the call, but the callback never gets fired on the iPhone.

I don't have any other devices to test on at the moment.

Any ideas?  Is this a security thing for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the iPhone firmware to 4.3.3 fixed the issue.